# What are these connections in google-chrome/macos

Tags: networking, google-chrome

I see a large number of local network connections on google-chrome. is this just javascript trying to access local data through a socket, or is something more suspicious going on?

[image]

Comment: What is running on `localhost:443`?

Comment: I am not necessarily sure. how do I figure this out?

Comment: Ok, I figure out whats running: `/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/Frameworks/Google Chrome Framework.framework/Versions/103.0.5060.53/Helpers/Google Chrome Helper.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome Helper` but does it make sense that Google Chrome Helper would be connecting to localhost?

Comment: It would. It's fairly common to have inter-process communication happening via the network stack, especially on Unix-style systems. For example, on Linux, the entire graphical interface system (X11) communicates via the network stack.

Comment: appreciate the answer @mtak if you post it as a answer, I will accept it.